Is VSSOP-8 packaging any different from SOP-8?
Are these two packaging titles similar with different names or is there actually a difference?
(please provide both sizes in mils if different)
The device in question is a INA821

Is the question whether what is called VSSOP-8 in this arbitrary Texas Instruments datasheet, is the same as a hypothetical other component possibly by another manufacturer, that is named SOP-8?

I haven't performed a full search of packages, but found the question  What are the known ambiguous SMD IC package which starts with:

I just recently discovered (the hard way...) that VSSOP-8 is an ambiguous IC package name. Some manufacturers use this name to describe a 0.65mm pitch device, whereas others use VSSOP-8 to describe a narrower 0.5mm pitch device

The answer in the above referenced that question says to lookup IPC-7351B, rather than use the short name.
For this specific question, the TI INA821 datasheet the VSSOP Package Type as the TI Package Drawing DGK. The datasheet includes the following for the DGK0008A VSSOP - 1.1 mm max height package:

Package dimensions
Land Pattern Example
Solder Mask Details
Solder Paste Example


SOP-8 package is bigger than VSSOP-8, about double size.
For SOP and SOIC the lead pitch (legs separation) is 1.27mm.
For VSSOP, and MSOP, it's 0.50mm or 0.65mm, or even 0.40mm I think.
And there are other similar variants. For me this is a mess. It's better to check the dimensions in the datasheet.

MSOP can also be 0.5 mm. I think it can be 0.4 mm too, for higher pin counts.

Ok, I adjust the answer. Thanks.
